# Encontrar posición de una palabra en un archivo de texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando encontrar la posición de la palabra **ABC** en un archivo de texto que contiene una string de varías líneas, he probado lo siguiente:

```
f = open(r'file.txt','r')
s = 'ABC'
inx = f.find(s)
print (inx+3)
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Que significa este error? Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

estás tratando de usar `find()` en un objeto de tupo `'_io.TextIOWrapper'`
para traer el texto del archivo que intentas leer, es necesario usar el método `read()` de dicho objeto, por lo que tu código podría quedar

```
with open (r'file.txt','r') as file:
   s = 'ABC'
   f = file.read()
   inx = f.find(s)
   print (inx+3)
```

La parte del `with` es una parte interesante, se usa comúnmente para abrir archivos de python, puedes echarle un ojo [Aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/)